# Neo4j Could not apply the transaction to the store after written to log and application restart

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver

At my Neo4j 3.1.3/SDN 4 project from time to time I'm facing with a following Neo4j exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionException: Could not apply the transaction to the store after written to log
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.executeRequest(BoltRequest.java:175)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.execute(BoltRequest.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.autoindex.AutoIndexManager.assertIndexes(AutoIndexManager.java:187)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.autoindex.AutoIndexManager.build(AutoIndexManager.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:93)
    at com.example.domain.api.configuration.Neo4jConfig.sessionFactory(Neo4jConfig.java:38)
    at com.example.domain.api.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bcccfdf9.CGLIB$sessionFactory$2(<generated>)
    at com.example.domain.api.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bcccfdf9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e2dbf1bb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.example.domain.api.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bcccfdf9.sessionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

I use Bolt driver in order to connect to Neo4j.

In order to solve this situation I have to restart my Neo4j server and also I have to restart my application(restart Tomcat server).

Is it possible to configure my Bolt driver/datasource.. etc in order to get my application up and running with no needs to restart the application itself.. only restart neo4j server ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is related to OGM, it rather looks a problem on the db side.
Maybe report this on the neo4j gitub with relevant db logs.

Disabling index checks at application startup might help.
This can be done by removing `indexes.auto` entry from `ogm.properties` file (or equivalent java config).
see http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:indexing